# What is the list of possible tags with a description of CoNLL 2003 NER Task?

Tags: tags, named-entity-recognition, conll

I need to do some NER. I've found [DeepPavlov](https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov) library that does this.

Here is an example from [docs](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/latest/components/ner.html):

```py
from deeppavlov import configs, build_model

ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes, download=True)
ner_model(['Bob Ross lived in Florida'])
>>> [[['Bob', 'Ross', 'lived', 'in', 'Florida']], [['B-PERSON', 'I-PERSON', 'O', 'O', 'B-GPE']]]
```

I don't understand what all those tags mean. As I understood from the documentation, they are in the CoNLL 2003 NER Task format.

Can somebody point me at the list of possible tags with a description of CoNLL 2003 NER Task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For NER task there are some common types of entities used as tags:

- persons (PER)
- organizations (ORG)
- monetary values (MONEY)
- Geopolitical entity, i.e. countries, cities, states (GPE)

and many others

Furthermore, to distinguish adjacent entities with the same tag many applications use BIO tagging scheme. Here **B** denotes the beginning of an entity, **I** stands for "inside" and is used for all words comprising the entity except the first one, and **O** means the absence of entity.

So on the example above, **B-PERSON** means that the person name begins with the token *Bob*, the next tag **I-PERSON** says that *Ross* relates to the entity as the previous tag. Then goes **O** which means that *lived* doesn't belong to any entity, the same is with *in*, whereas *Florida* is the begginging of **Geopolitical entity (GPE)**.

Please let me know if this was helpful enough.

Comment: How to create those tags for your own data?